# Print a list of words in random order - Python

Tags: python, list

I have a project to complete from a book which was received as a Christmas present (Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner, Third Edition):

*Create a program that prints a list of words in random order. The program should print all the words and not repeat any.*

I have created the following code:

```
import random

words = ["Please", "Help", "Me", "Merry", "Christmas"]

for i in range(len(words)):
    random_index = random.randrange(len(words))
    print(words[random_index])
    del words[random_index]
```

I'd like to check if this code is the most efficient way of doing so, but there is no forum to check against, rather frustratingly!

Is there a better way of doing this? Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> import random
>>> words = ["Please", "Help", "Me", "Merry", "Christmas"]
>>> random.sample(words, len(words))
['Merry', 'Me', 'Help', 'Please', 'Christmas']
```

or [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) if it is okay to modify the original list:

```
>>> random.shuffle(words)
>>> words
['Me', 'Merry', 'Help', 'Please', 'Christmas']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only the things the chapter is about, than maybe this could be one solution:

```
import random

myList = ["create", "a", "program", "that", "prints"]

for i in range(len(myList)):
    randomWord = random.choice(myList)
    print(randomWord)
    myList.remove(randomWord)

input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
random.shuffle(words)
print words
```

Random is module which provides you with an inbuilt method called, shuffle() , which can be used to change the elements of the list argument passed in any random order.

Answer (score 1):

Other than using Python's `sample` or `shuffle` function directly as others have suggested, your solution works just fine, but it has the downside of emptying the original `words` list, which is probably not desirable.

To that end, the following does both in-place and copy shuffle.

```
import random

words = ["Please", "Help", "Me", "Merry", "Christmas"]

# in-place or copy shuffle 
def shuffle(in_words, copy=False):
    in_words = in_words[:] if copy else in_words
    for i in range(len(in_words)):
        pos = random.randrange(len(in_words))
        in_words[i], in_words[pos] = in_words[pos], in_words[i]
    return in_words
# see if it works
print "unshuffled", words
print "shuffled %s (was: %s)" % (shuffle(words, copy=True), words)
print "in-place shuffled", shuffle(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

import random

```
words = ["Please", "Help", "Me", "Merry", "Christmas"]

for i in range(len(words)):
    random_index = random.randrange(len(words))
    print(words.pop(random_index))
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation and why is it more efficient (e.g. is it faster or just less code, more readable, uses best practices, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

words = ["Please", "Help", "Me", "Merry", "Christmas"]
wordsUsed = []
print()

while len(wordsUsed) != len(words):
    choice = random.choice(words)
    if choice not in wordsUsed:
        print(choice)
        wordsUsed.append(choice)

input("\nPress the enter key to exit..")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Random word printer

import random
WORDS = ["joy","hope","kindness","love","patience","dedication"]
used = []
while WORDS:
    comp_choice = random.choice(WORDS)
    if comp_choice not in used:
        print(comp_choice,end = " ")
    used.append(comp_choice)

Comment: Hi there - while this answer may be correct, it would be considerable more useful to other users if it **explained** why it was correct. What does this answer do that other answers did not, and why is it the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but it uses only the methods which were mentioned in the book so far.

```
import random

init_list = ["i", "need", "coffee", "break", "and", "to", "go", "home"]
new_list = []

for i in range(len(init_list)):
    n = random.randint(len(init_list)-1)
    new_list.append(init_list[n])
    del init_list[n]

print(new_list)
input("Press Enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

import random

word_list = [“Seconds”, “Minutes”, “Hours”, “Days”, “Weeks”, “Months”, “years”]

new_list = []

for i in range (len(word_list)):
ran_word
random.choice(word_list)
new_list.append(ran_word)
if ran_word in new_list:
word_list.remove(ran_word)
for i in new_list:
print (i)

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
list=["hello","bye","good night","welcome"]

new_list=[]

import random


while len(new_list)!=4:

   word=random.choice(list)

   if word not in new_list:

      new_list.append(word)

   else:

      new_word.remove(word)

print(new_list)
```